# ASCII, ISO 8859-1, Unicode in C how does it work?

Tags: c, terminal, utf-8, console-application, iso-8859-1

Well, I'm really in doubt, how does C work with encodings, well first I have a C file, saved with ISO 8859-1 encoding, with test.c content, when running the program the character ÿ is not displayed correctly on the linux console, I know that by default it uses utf-8, but if utf-8 uses the same 256 characters as ISO 8859-1, why doesn't the program correctly display the 'ÿ' character? Another question, why does test2 correctly display the 'ÿ' character? where the test2.c file is a UTF-8 and also the file.txt is a UTF-8 ? In other words, wasn't the compiler to complain about the width being multi-character?

test1.c

```
  // ISO 8859-1
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void)
  {
    unsigned char c = 'ÿ';
    putchar(c);
    return 0;
  }

  $ gcc -o test1 test1.c
  $ ./test1
  $ ▒
```

test2.c

```
  // ASCII
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void) 
  {

     FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
     int c;

     while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
     return 0;
 }
```

file.txt: UTF-8
abcdefÿghi

```
  $ gcc -o test2 test2.c
  $ ./test2
  $ abcdefÿghi
```

well, that's it, if you can help me giving details about it I would be very grateful, :)

Comment: `if utf-8 uses the same 256 characters as ISO 8859-1` Nope. They are different ways to encode characters as bytes.

Comment: I put a printf there, and I saw that the character 'ÿ' is encoded with the integers 191 and 195, but why is that? since the unicode utf-8 value is 00ff, that is, 1 byte is 255 and the rest is zeroed? @stark

Comment: The character `ÿ` is encoded (in UTF-8) as the two-byte `0xC3 0xBF`. It did not cause a compiler because you put it in a string, which by definition can contain multiple characters. If you try to assign it to a single `char` (`char chr = 'ÿ';`) you *WILL*get an error. And if you calculate the `strlen` of a string containing `ÿ`, you will find that length to be one more than you might expect.

Comment: Unicode value is 00ff. When 00ff is encoded as utf-8 that is 2 bytes. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: @Yuri, you might want to read the Wikipedia article on UTF-8, especially the section titled "Encoding" [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding].

Comment: @SGeorgiadesBut how does the putchar function know, that that character is more than 1 a byte ?

Comment: each call to putchar writes 1 byte to stdout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character encodings can be confusing for many reasons. Here are some explanations:

In the ISO 8859-1 encoding, the character **y** with a diaeresis **ÿ** (originally a ligature of **i** and **j**) is encoded as a byte value of `0xFF` (255). The first 256 code points in Unicode **do** correspond to the same characters as the ones from ISO 8859-1, but the popular UTF-8 encoding for Unicode uses 2 bytes for code points larger than 127, so `ÿ` is encoded in UTF-8 as `0xC3 0xBF`.

When you read the file **file.txt**, your program reads one byte at a time and outputs it to the console unchanged (except for line endings on legacy systems), the `ÿ` is read as 2 separate bytes which are output one after the other, and the terminal displays `ÿ` because the locale selected for the terminal also uses the UTF-8 encoding.

Adding to confusion, if the source file uses UTF-8 encoding, `"ÿ"` is a string of length 2 and `'ÿ'` is parsed as a multibyte character constant. Multibyte character constants are very confusing and non portable (the value can be 0xC3BF or 0xBFC3 depending on the system), using them is strongly discouraged and the compiler should be configured to issue a warning when it sees one (`gcc -Wall -Wextra`).

Even more confusing is this: on many systems the type `char` signed by default. In this case, the character constant `'ÿ'` (a single byte in ISO 8859-1) has a value of `-1` and type `int`, no matter how you write it in the source code: `'\377'` and `'\xff'` will also have a value of `-1`. The reason for this is consistency with the value of `"ÿ"[0]`, a `char` with the value `-1`. This is also the most common value of the macro `EOF`.

On all systems, `getchar()` and similar functions like `getc()` and `fgetc()` return values between `0` and `UCHAR_MAX` or the special negative value of `EOF`, so the byte 0xFF from a file where character `ÿ` in encoded as ISO 8859-1 is returned as the value `0xFF` or `255`, which compares different from `'ÿ'` if `char` is signed, and also different from `'ÿ'` if the source code is in UTF-8.

As a rule of thumb, do not use non-ASCII characters in character constants, do not make assumptions about the character encoding used for strings and file contents and configure the compiler to make `char` unsigned by default (`-funsigned-char`).

If you deal with foreign languages, using UTF-8 is highly recommended for all textual contents, including source code. Be aware that non-ASCII characters are encoded as multiple bytes with this encoding.  Study the [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding), it is quite simple and elegant, and use libraries to handle textual transformations such as uppercasing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `unsigned char` represents an unsigned integer of size 8 bits (from 0 to 255). C uses ASCII values to represent characters. An ASCII character is simply an integer from 0 to 127. For example, `A` is 65.

When you use `'A'`, the compiler understands `65`. But, `'ÿ'` is not an ASCII character, it is an extended ASCII character (with a value of 152). Technically, it can fit inside an `unsigned char` but the C standard requires that the syntax `''` contains a standard ASCII character.

So that's why the first example didn't work.

Now for the second one. A non ASCII character cannot fit into a single char. The way you can handle characters outside the limited ASCII set is by using several chars. When you write `ÿ` into a file, you are actually writing a binary representation of this character. If you are using the `UTF-8` reprensentation, this means that in you file you have two 8-bit numbers `0xC3` and `0xBF`.

When you read your file in the while loop of `test2.c`, at some point, `c` will take the value `0xC3` and then `0xBF` on the next iteration. These two values will be given to `putc`. And then, when displayed, the two values together will be interpreted as `ÿ`.

When `putc` finally writes the characters, they eventually are read by your terminal application. If it supports `UTF-8` encoding, it can understand the meaning of `0xC3` followed by `0xBF` and display a `ÿ`.

So the reason why, in the first example, you didn't see `ÿ` is that the value of `c` in your code is actually (probably) `0xC3` which doesn't reprensent any character.

A more concrete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char y[3] = { 0xC3, 0xBF, '\0' };
    printf("%s\n", y);
}
```

This will display `ÿ` but as you can see, it takes 2 chars to do that.

Comment: `ÿ` has a value of 255 in ISO 8859-1 and Windows 1252, and 152 in CP437 and CP850.

Comment: *the C standard requires that the syntax '' contains a standard ASCII character*: no it does not: **5.2.1 Charater sets** [...] *In a character constant or string literal, members of the execution character set shall be represented by corresponding members of the source character set or by escape sequences consisting of the backslash \ followed by one or more characters. A byte with all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string.*

Comment: @chqrlie You're right, my bad. That was a very poor choice of words. A more accurate way to put it is that the conversion of a multi-character literal to a char is implementation defined. If the compiler uses an UTF-8 encoding, `'ÿ'` is then a 2 byte character which means that it will be implicitly converted to something like `0xC3` or `0xBF` depending on the implementation.

Comment: Not exactly: **6.4.4.4 Character constants** [...] *An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single- quotes, as in’x’. A wide character constant is the same, except prefixed by the letterL,u, orU. With a few exceptions detailed later, the elements of the sequence are any members of the source character set; they are mapped in an implementation-defined manner to members of the execution character set.*

Comment: Consequently, in a source file encoded in UTF-8, `'ÿ'` may be equivalent to `'\xC3\xBF'` or not and its value is implementation defined: `clang` refuses to compile `'ÿ'` on OS/X (`error: character too large for enclosing character literal type`) whereas `gcc` on linux relunctantly parses both as character constants with a value of `0xc3bf`, with this warning `warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`

Comment: Right, but I'm talking about the conversion between `'ÿ'` (which may have a value of `0xC3BF` to a char which is the issue here. As far as I know, this conversion is implementation specific (which is why I wrongly said that the standard does not support it). Am I wrong in saying that?

Comment: The conversion from the `int` value `'ÿ'` to `unsigned char` performed to store it to `c` is fully defined by the C Standard: **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers** *1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than_Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.[...]*

Comment: *[...]3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.* so, assuming 32-bit `int` and 8-bit `char`, storing `0xC3BF` to `c` effectively stores `0xBF`. What is implementation defined in the actual value of `'ÿ'`...

Answer (score 1):

*if utf-8 uses the same 256 characters as ISO 8859-1*. No there is a confusion here. In ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin1) the 256 characters have indeed the code point value of the corresponding Unicode character. But utf-8 have a special encoding for all characters above 0x7f and all characters having a code point between 0x80 and 0xff are represented as 2 bytes. For example the character `é` U+00e9 is represented as the single byte 0xe9 in ISO-8859-1, but is represented as the 2 bytes 0xc3 0xa9 in utf-8.

More references on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to reproduce on MacOS with clang:

```
$ gcc -o test1 test1.c
test1.c:6:23: warning: illegal character encoding in character literal [-Winvalid-source-encoding]
    unsigned char c = '<FF>';
                      ^
1 warning generated.

$ ./test1
?

$ gcc -finput-charset=iso-8859-1 -o test1 test1.c
clang: error: invalid value 'iso-8859-1' in '-finput-charset=iso-8859-1'
```

clang on MacOS has UTF-8 as default.

Encoded in UTF-8:

```
$ gcc -o test1 test1.c
test1.c:6:23: error: character too large for enclosing character literal type
    unsigned char c = 'ÿ';
                      ^
1 error generated.
```

Debugging all warnings and errors we get a solution with the correct string literal and an array of bytes:

```
// UTF-8
  #include <stdio.h>

// needed for correct strings
  #include <string.h>

  int main(void)
  {
    char c[] = "ÿ";
    int len  = strlen(c);
    printf("len: %u c[0]: %u \n", len, (unsigned char)c[0] );

    putchar(c[0]);
    return 0;
  }

$ ./test1
len: 2 c[0]: 195
?
```

Decimal `195` is hexadecimal `C3`, which is exactly the first byte of the UTF-8 byte sequence of the character `ÿ`:

```
$ uni identify ÿ
     cpoint  dec    utf-8       html       name
'ÿ'  U+00FF  255    c3 bf       &yuml;     LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS (Lowercase_Letter)
                    ^^ <-- HERE
```

Now we know that we must output 2 bytes and code:

```
    char c[] = "ÿ";
    int len  = strlen(c);

    for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
        putchar(c[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

$ ./test1 
ÿ
```

Program `test2.c` just reads bytes and outputs them. If the input is UTF-8 then the output is also UTF-8. This just keeps the encoding.

To convert Latin-1 to UTF-8 we need to pack it in a special way. For two bytes of UTF-8 we need a begin byte `110x xxxx` (number of bits at the begin is the length of the sequence in bytes) and a continuation byte `10xx xxxx`.

We can code now:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdint.h>

  int main(void)
  {
    uint8_t latin1 = 255; // code point of 'ÿ'  U+00FF  255

    uint8_t byte1 = 0b11000000 | ((latin1 & 0b11000000) >> 6);
    uint8_t byte2 = 0b10000000 |  (latin1 & 0b00111111);

    putchar(byte1);
    putchar(byte2);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
  }

$ ./test1
ÿ
```

This works only for ISO-8859-1 ("true" Latin-1). Many files called "Latin-1" are encoded in Windows/Microsoft CP1252.

Comment: Binary literals such as `0b11000000` use an extension not yet part of the C Standard. You should probably write `0xC0` instead.